# How to add a fog layer in Mapbox for iOS

Tags: swift, mapbox-ios

I am trying to add a fog layer in my iOS app using Mapbox SDK, however so far without success. I would like to use this to achieve the effect of partially hiding distant map content to achieve a better 3D effect at camera pitch 90. Adding the sky layer was simple enough, but cannot see how to add a fog layer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achieve this you can take a look at [Atmosphere](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/api/10.10.0/Structs/Atmosphere.html)

```
var atmosphere = Atmosphere()
// code to configure Atmosphere here
try mapView.mapboxMap.style.setAtmosphere(atmosphere)
```

[image: 3D Terrain with fog]

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Just need to have a play around with the parameters now.